# Podcast Episode Sort Order

Tags: 2sxc

How do I change the sort order of the episodes in the Podcast app?  Currently it looks like it is descending order on Date.  I have added custom fields for Season and Episode number and need to sort that way.

Answer (score 0):

The data is prepared in a visual query. So you have two options:

1. Either you change the query (or copy/create a new one) to match your needs
2. Or you continue to use the query but use LINQ in the Razor file to do some more filtering/sorting